# call a java method using runtime.exec()

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, runtime.exec

In my java code there is class A that has the following line:

```
Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myString);
```

where myString is user supplied input and is passed to `exec()` at runtime.

Also there is a public method `doSomething()` in class `A`.

Can I somehow invoke `doSomething()` (through reflection, jdwp etc.) using exec() at runtime ?

Comment: Classic XY problem. You want to do X but you are asking about Y. Forget the `Runtime.exec()` part of it and focus on the *problem.*

Comment: all i want to do is invoke doSomething() at runtime and this **needs** to be done without making any changes to the existing code. The only thing that can be modified is the myString parameter as it is a user supplied value passed to the program at runtime.

Comment: You can't call a specific method externally without writing some code.  Note: even if you call a method, this won't pass an object to the JVM to use as state/context. It is just a static method call, or a call on a newly constructed instance.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a new JVM just to call a single method? First, that would be really slow. And second, it would be highly unnecessary!

Reflection is what you want I guess. Here's some sample code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<Main> c = Main.class; // First get the class
        try {
            Method method = c.getMethod("doSomething"); // get the method by its name
            method.invoke(new Main()); // call it on a new instance of Main
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
           System.out.println("Method is not found"); // print something when the method is not found
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I have done something!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is ... it still doesn't make sense in the context of his question. If you are able to run **additional** code inside his existing JVM; then you do absolutely not need the detour of using reflection. And if he can't execute code in the context of his existing JVM, reflection will not solve his problem either.

Comment: @GhostCat The OP seems to have gotten a string. And this string seems to be the name of a method that he/she wants to call. So why not use reflection?

Comment: I just told you: you dont need to do reflection.callMethod("doSomething"); you can just write down "doSomething()" instead. When you know how a method is called, and when you can execute code ... you do not need the reflection detour. But most likely, his requirements are actually more complicated, but alas, he isn't able to communicate them.

Comment: @Sweeper I would agree, it would be slow & completely ugly. But, again, this is not a typical development project. And my primary concern as a security consultant is to break the existing software somehow. One way to exploit the vulnerability that I have identified with the code is what I have asked (minus the noise) above in the question. The problem is, through the exec() that's present in the code, I am unable to write a new file on the disk, because redirection is not supported by exec(String cmd) & hence I can't do something like exec("cat some_java_code > xyz.java"). Makes sense ?

Answer (score 1):

That would mean starting a **whole new** JVM just to make a method call.
If you are already "within" class A; what prevents you from calling doSomething() directly? Probably: only your lack of skills. If so, then work on your skills; and don't go for the next best solution you heard somebody mention how things might be done!

In essence: a self-claimed **geek** should **always** understand each and any concept he is using in his programs. If you want to use reflection, then study what **reflection** is about.

And please note: letting your users pass in **arbitrary** strings to have them executed, is a **huge** security **NO GO**. You should have mentioned in your question that you want to do this on purpose; and that you are fully aware of the potential consequences of doing so!

EDIT; given your latest comments.

In this case, a solution could be as simple as:

A) you write a new class, like

```
public class Invoker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A.doSomething();
```

or if doSomething isn't static, you will need

```
    A someA = new A( ... however you can create instances of A
    A.doSomething()
```

B) Compile that, and then you can simply send a command like

```
java -cp WHATEVER Invoker
```

into your existing application. Of course, you have to work out the details; like providing a valid classpath to that call to java (that classpath has to include the location where Invoker.class lives; and of course A.class; and all of the dependencies that A has).

But keep in mind: doSomething() is executed in the scope of a different JVM. That means that most likely, it will **not at all** affect class A in that JVM where you trigger the call to **exec**!